# How to add new field and copy the value from existing field if its not null in mongo using a query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to add new fields to all the documents in a mongo collection based on the values of other fields only if they are not null. I have written a script to do this, but is there a single query with which we can accomplish this?

sample data:

```
[{
        "outdoor": {
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -92.41151,
                    35.11683
                ]
            }
        },
"address": {    "street1" : "Street 1",
        "postalCode" : "95050",
        "state" : "CA",
        "locality" : "City 1",
        "countryCode" : "US"},
"customerId":"8047380094"

    },
    {
        "outdoor": {
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -89.58342,
                    36.859161
                ]
            }
        },
        "customerId":"8047380094"
    },
    {
        "address": {

                "street1" : "Street 1",
        "postalCode" : "95050",
        "state" : "CA",
        "locality" : "City 1",
        "countryCode" : "US"
        },
      "customerId":"8047380094"
    }]
```

Need to add below new fields:

1. new_address - copy address data into this field if its not null
2. new_location - copy outdoor.location into this field if its not null

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Mongo Aggregation Pipeline support for update commands available starting from MongoDB version 4.2

```
db.collection.updateMany({
  "address": {
    "$ne": null
  }
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "new_address": "$address"
    },
  }
])
```

```
db.collection.updateMany({
  "outdoor.location": {
    "$ne": null
  }
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "new_location": "$outdoor.location"
    },
  }
])
```